# Задание имени библиотеки, используя generator expressions

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, cmake

Пытаюсь задать название библиотеки, используя generator expressions, однако получаю ошибку сборки:

> fatal error U1001: syntax error : illegal character '<' in macro

Полный текст `CMakeLists.txt` (2ой таргет проверяет правильность generator expression):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(my_lib)

add_library(my_lib SHARED library.cpp library.h)
set_target_properties(my_lib PROPERTIES
                      PREFIX ""
                      DEBUG_POSTFIX "_d"
                      SUFFIX ".$<IF:$<PLATFORM_ID:Windows>,dll,so>")

add_custom_target(debug_generator_expression COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo ".$<IF:$<PLATFORM_ID:Windows>,dll,so>")
```

Похоже `nmake` почему-то использует не раскрытое выражение `.dll`, а полную строку в качестве суффикса. Как исправить?

Comment: В доках поддержка generator expressions в директиве set_target_properties не заявляется

Comment: @VTT а она (поддержка) должна явно указываться?

Comment: Ну в местах, где она есть, об этом пишут явно, например `Arguments to target_include_directories may use “generator expressions” with the syntax $<...>.`

Comment: @VTT Тогда придётся использовать простой if()

Comment: @VTT это должно быть ответом, я думаю.

Answer (score 0):

Про поддержку generator expressions для **свойств** (properties) надо читать в описании самого свойства.

Например, описание свойства [SUFFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/SUFFIX.html)

> What comes after the target name.
>
> A target property that can be set to override the suffix (such as .so or .exe)
> on the name of a library, module or executable.

не содержит никакого упоминания generator expressions, а значит не поддерживает его.

На самом деле, generator expressions не являются прямой заменой `if`.
Их смысл раскрывается только при **многоцелевой** конфигурации проекта, когда за один запуск `cmake` проект конфигурируется **сразу** под несколько задач. Например, под Release и Debug.

Но так как ни один из генераторов проектов ([CMake generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html)) не поддерживает одновременную конфигурацию под Windows и Linux, то в данном случае нет ничего плохого в `if`:

```
if(WIN32)
  set(SHARED_LIB_SUFFIX ".dll")
else()
  set(SHARED_LIB_SUFFIX ".so")
endif()

set_target_properties(my_lib PROPERTIES
                      PREFIX ""
                      DEBUG_POSTFIX "_d"
                      SUFFIX "${SHARED_LIB_SUFFIX}")
```

Между прочим, в CMake есть готовая переменная [CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX.html), содержащая расширение разделяемых (shared) библиотек на платформе, под которую собирается проект.